# Add new line to a file (txt) after cin in c++

Tags: c++, input, newline, cin

I am trying to insert some characters as input from the user and save that input to a text file. The input data is correctly added to the text file, but the problem is that I cannot add a new line.

For example, my input is:

```
a

s


d

f

g
```

When I open the file, the data is displayed as follows:

```
asdfg
```

How can I fix this problem?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

class StartMenu {
    private:
        string option;
    public:
        bool repeat = false;
        bool load = false;
        bool start = false;
        char MenuOption;

        void start_menu(){

            cout << endl;
            cout << "  Chose one Option to be excuted: " << endl;
            cout << "  To quite press:          0 " << endl ;
            cout << "  To load the game press:      1" << endl;
            cout << "  To Start new Game press:         2" << endl;
            cin >> MenuOption;

            switch(MenuOption) {
                case 48:
                    option = "quite" ;
                    repeat = true;
                    cout << "You choose " << MenuOption << " the game will " << option << endl;
                    break;
                case 49:
                    option = "Load " ;
                    repeat = true;
                    load = true;
                    cout << "You choose " << MenuOption << " the game will " << option << endl;
                    break;
                case 50:
                    option = "Start " ;
                    repeat = true;
                    start = true;
                    cout << "You choose " << MenuOption << " the game will " << option << endl;
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    cout << MenuOption <<" Number not found " << endl;
                    cout << "Please Enter a number between 0 - 2 "  << endl;
            }
        }
};

class Save_game {
    public:
        int openFile(){
            ofstream MyWriteFile("test2.txt");
            char write_to_info;
            string info[52];

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i += 2){
                cout << "write something" << endl;
                cin >> write_to_info;
                info[i] = write_to_info;
                //Write to the file
                MyWriteFile << info[i] << endl;
            }
   
            // Close the file
            MyWriteFile.close();
            return 0;
        }
};

//Load Game Class 
class load_game {
    public:
        // Create a text string, which is used to output the text file
        string my_last_game;

        // Read from the text file
        void Load_game(){
      
            ifstream MyReadFile("test2.txt");

            // Use a while loop together with the getline() function to read the file line by line
            while (getline (MyReadFile, my_last_game)) {
                //Output the text from the file
                cout << my_last_game;
            }

            // Close the file
            MyReadFile.close();
        }
};

int main(){

    StartMenu mymenu;
    Save_game saved_game;
    load_game Load_Last_game;
   
    while(mymenu.repeat==false){
        mymenu.start_menu();
    }

    if(mymenu.start==true){
        saved_game.openFile();
    }
    
    if(mymenu.load==true){
        Load_Last_game.Load_game();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Did you consider `std::endl`??

Comment: I have fixed the formatting of your question regarding the input, but I am not sure if you added the additional newline characters for formatting purposes or if they are indeed intended to be part of the input. Please verify that the input is now correct and remove the newline characters if appropriate.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I believe they are using `endl`. I'm wondering if they're running it on a system that doesn't convert `\n` to `\r\n`, and reading it in a Windows text editor like notepad that doesn't recognize `\n` alone. That said, the place they use it (in definition of `class Save_game`) makes no sense (it's code outside any function, inside the class declaration), so this is clearly garbage code. We need a proper [MCVE].

Comment: the problem is that the data is written like that  \   then **n** that why in the file it self did not consider as a  new line.

Comment: The `operator>>` drops all leading space before reading anything. If you want to read everything use `std::getline()`

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I believe the code you are talking about is inside a function. The posted code compiles cleanly. Only the indentation was misleading. This has now been fixed by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following code:

```
while (getline (MyReadFile, my_last_game)) {
    //Output the text from the file
    cout << my_last_game;
}
```

The function call

```
getline (MyReadFile, my_last_game)
```

will read one line from the file and store it in the `std::string` named `my_last_game`, but will not store the newline character in the string. Instead, the newline character will be discarded.

Therefore, if you want to print a newline character, you will have to explicitly print it, by changing the line

```
cout << my_last_game;
```

to:

```
cout << my_last_game << '\n';
```